# How to export private key from a keystore of self-signed certificate

Tags: tomcat, ssl, certificate, self-signed, keystore

I just created a self-signed certificate on a linux box running tomcat 6.

I created the keys like this, valid for 10 years:

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcatorange -keyalg RSA -validity 3650
```

and copied the keystore into a folder in tomcat, and updated server.xml to point at the keystore.

Now my network admin is asking for the both the public and private key ( for our load balancer)

I can generate the public key using:

```
openssl s_client -connect mydomain.com:8443
```

But how can I export/retrieve the private key?

Comment: A nice reference https://8gwifi.org/docs/jks.jsp

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It is a little tricky. First you can use [keytool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html) to put the private key into PKCS12 format, which is more portable/compatible than Java's various keystore formats. Here is an example taking a private key with alias 'mykey' in a Java keystore and copying it into a PKCS12 file named `myp12file.p12`.
[note that on most screens this command extends beyond the right side of the box: you need to scroll right to see it all]

```
keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore .keystore -srcalias mykey -destkeystore myp12file.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12
Enter destination keystore password:  
Re-enter new password: 
Enter source keystore password:  
[Storing myp12file.p12]
```

Now the file `myp12file.p12` contains the private key in PKCS12 format which may be used directly by many software packages or further processed using the [`openssl pkcs12`](http://openssl.org/docs/apps/pkcs12.html#) command. For example,

```
openssl pkcs12 -in myp12file.p12 -nocerts -nodes
Enter Import Password:
MAC verified OK
Bag Attributes
    friendlyName: mykey
    localKeyID: 54 69 6D 65 20 31 32 37 31 32 37 38 35 37 36 32 35 37 
Key Attributes: <No Attributes>
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIC...
.
.
.
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Prints out the private key unencrypted.

Note that this is a *private key*, and *you* are responsible for appreciating the security implications of removing it from your Java keystore and moving it around.

Comment: The openssl command above gives the following error:   6016:error:0D07207B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:header too long:.\crypto\asn1\asn1_lib.c:150:

Comment: @user265330: Sorry to hear that, but it worked for me. What version of openssl are you using?

Comment: OMG thank you.  Been pulling my hair out for three days on this.  Only to discover I had been using the wrong private.key.  I was able to extract the private.key from the JKS and it works.  +10000 for you.

Comment: For everyone getting the "Error outputting keys and certificates" error: try using the same password for source and destination.

Comment: In case anyone else has the same problem as @user265330, try scrolling right on the code box in the answer and including the -deststoretype parameter. Not that I did this, or anything...

Comment: @DaveMulligan That was indeed the problem that I was facing. Thanks for pointing it out. Curious, how do I cross check that the private key that I generated is indeed the correct one for my certificate?. In my case, I imported the PC7B format certificate into JKS and I have got a key from the above command. What does this private key correspond to in my case?.

Comment: @DaveMulligan: I can move the command-line arguments around if you think it would help. I could also break it into two or more lines, but I think it might look ugly.

Answer (score 6):

Use Keystore Explorer gui - http://keystore-explorer.sourceforge.net/ - allows you to extract the private key from a .jks in various formats.

Answer (score 2):

http://anandsekar.github.io/exporting-the-private-key-from-a-jks-keystore/

```
public class ExportPrivateKey {
        private File keystoreFile;
        private String keyStoreType;
        private char[] password;
        private String alias;
        private File exportedFile;

        public static KeyPair getPrivateKey(KeyStore keystore, String alias, char[] password) {
                try {
                        Key key=keystore.getKey(alias,password);
                        if(key instanceof PrivateKey) {
                                Certificate cert=keystore.getCertificate(alias);
                                PublicKey publicKey=cert.getPublicKey();
                                return new KeyPair(publicKey,(PrivateKey)key);
                        }
                } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        }
        return null;
        }

        public void export() throws Exception{
                KeyStore keystore=KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
                BASE64Encoder encoder=new BASE64Encoder();
                keystore.load(new FileInputStream(keystoreFile),password);
                KeyPair keyPair=getPrivateKey(keystore,alias,password);
                PrivateKey privateKey=keyPair.getPrivate();
                String encoded=encoder.encode(privateKey.getEncoded());
                FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(exportedFile);
                fw.write(“—–BEGIN PRIVATE KEY—–\n“);
                fw.write(encoded);
                fw.write(“\n“);
                fw.write(“—–END PRIVATE KEY—–”);
                fw.close();
        }


        public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
                ExportPrivateKey export=new ExportPrivateKey();
                export.keystoreFile=new File(args[0]);
                export.keyStoreType=args[1];
                export.password=args[2].toCharArray();
                export.alias=args[3];
                export.exportedFile=new File(args[4]);
                export.export();
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
try {
        String keystorePass = "20174";
        String keyPass = "rav@789";
        String alias = "TyaGi!";
        InputStream keystoreStream = new FileInputStream("D:/keyFile.jks");
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");
        keystore.load(keystoreStream, keystorePass.toCharArray());
        Key key = keystore.getKey(alias, keyPass.toCharArray());

        byte[] bt = key.getEncoded();
        String s = new String(bt);
        System.out.println("------>"+s);      
        String str12 = Base64.encodeBase64String(bt);

        System.out.println("Fetched Key From JKS : " + str12);

    } catch (KeyStoreException | IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException | UnrecoverableKeyException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);

    }
}
```