# How to load SSL Certificate in Java

Tags: java, ssl

I am creating a Java program to get information from a server but I have to perform a ssl handshake with the server from the Java program.

I have `myfilercert.cer` file certificate for authentication purpose but I have no idea how I can load that certificate in java so that the java program can perform 'handshake' with the server where I want to get information from. Where to begin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Apache HttpClient (or just use the required classes from it to use `SslContextBuilder`, really), and then it'd be like so:

```
        SSLContextBuilder sslContextBuilder = SSLContextBuilder.create();
        sslContextBuilder.loadTrustMaterial(new File("yourTrustStore.jks"), "thePassWord");
        SSLContext sslContext = sslContextBuilder.build();
        HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) (new URL("https://thesite.com").openConnection());
        httpsURLConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```

But you need to create a keystore for your certificate, which can be done with keytool. If you need this for android, you'll need SpongyCastle library, and use that as a provider for KeyTool to create a BKS keystore instead of a JKS keystore; and you will need to explicitly open the KeyStore in Java.

```
                KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS",
                                                         BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
                byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(keyStoreBytes);
                keyStore.load(byteArrayInputStream, keyStorePassword);
                Certificate[] certificates = keyStore.getCertificateChain("theCertAlias");
                Certificate certificate = certificates[0];
```

Comment: Glad to hear that! :) if you've written up the commands you used with keytool to create the keystore you needed, then if you want, you can edit it into this post for future reference.

Comment: Can you help me to sort out this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50715251/invalid-algorithm-parameter-exception-generating-source-for-secured-soap-web-s ?

Answer (score 3):

What you need is the java [keystore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html). The keystore is a repository of security certificates used in SSL encryption.
You can read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19528-01/819-0997/aakhc/index.html) about the Server Authentication During SSL Handshake.  [This is a keystore tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/07/java-keystore-tutorial.html).

As an alternative to keytool, i would suggest a tool with a Graphical User Interface called [Portecle](http://sourceforge.net/projects/portecle/).  You can use it to browse the contents of your .cer file and see what's in it.

It can be useful to know about the [various certificate encodings](https://support.ssl.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/19/0/der-vs-crt-vs-cer-vs-pem-certificates-and-how-to-convert-them). Also read about the [X.509 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509).

[This is an article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/java-keytool-essentials-working-with-java-keystores) on java keytool essentials (which is the oracle tool that works with the java keystore).

You can google and find a lot of resources that instruct you how to generate. I think you will want to keep the certificate at the application level.

Some SO questions that helped me along the way:

- [Trust Store vs Key Store - creating with keytool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340918/trust-store-vs-key-store-creating-with-keytool) - important to know the difference between the trust manager and keymanager
- [Java HTTPS client certificate authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666052/java-https-client-certificate-authentication/1710543#1710543)
- [How to export private key from a keystore of self-signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640691/how-to-export-private-key-from-a-keystore-of-self-signed-certificate/2641032#2641032)
- [What is difference between cacerts and keystore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935619/what-is-difference-between-cacerts-and-keystore)
- [How to connect to a secure website using SSL in Java with a pkcs12 file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537040/how-to-connect-to-a-secure-website-using-ssl-in-java-with-a-pkcs12-file/573468#573468)
- [Received fatal alert: handshake_failure through SSLHandshakeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353849/received-fatal-alert-handshake-failure-through-sslhandshakeexception/6353956#6353956)
- [How to configure trustStore for javax.net.ssl.trustStore on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17712417/how-to-configure-truststore-for-javax-net-ssl-truststore-on-windows/26675773#26675773)

Good luck!