# How should I implement Certificate Authentication into my web service client?

Tags: java, web-services, certificate

I have created a web service client.I have been provided with a certificate "Certificate.Security.pfx" file, which I have placed on my local system.

I am looking for a java code example which shows how to access a secure web service over SSL using a PFX certificate.

I don't have any other details and this is my first time working with a certificate based web service. 
Browsing through the internet, somewhere I found I need to change it to "JKS". Is that true?

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: You can change it to JKS but that can also be bypassed. You need a keystore. Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/30953348/4807777 for a reference to other SO useful resources and tools to get you started.

Comment: Thanks Laurentiu, do I need to have/covert to .cer file?

Comment: Not necessarily. The cer file is what you usually receive when you connect to a webservice, from there you split it. You can just use the format you received, and inspect it with the tools recommended there. There are options vor every format to import into a keystore,use a different format for the keystore.

Comment: All looks good now with the certificate and keystore, but I am not able to connect to the host through Java code. I am getting a "java.net.UnknownHostException:" exception. Although I can access the host and wsdl link via browser.

Comment: To add to the previous comment. I have also disabled my system firewall. And my browser has a setting that use a Proxy Server. I can also access the host by using ping -t command on the command prompt.